# Google Charts API Graph With Custom Marker Icons

Tags: api, charts

I build a little script that makes draws a graph with the google charts api. http://pastebin.com/followersgraph.php

Now, i want to add custom markers images. I have an image ready to act as a marker.

In the Google Charts API documentation i cannot find how to add custom icons.

http://pastebin.com/i/nyan.png is the icon that should show up at each marker.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What, there's no built in nyanCat style? Google Charts is behind the times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
d=<marker_data_string> //string location of custom image
```

EXAMPLE:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x140&cht=lc&chco=FF9900,224499&
chd=t:75,74,66,30,10,5,3,1&chls=1|1&
chem=y;s=bubble_icon_text_small;d=ski,bb,Wheeee!,FFFFFF;dp=2;ds=0&chm=v,ccccFF,0,::.2,2
```

In that example, the "d=ski,bb,Wheeee!" i think that may be the custom marker image from what i can see on the Google Docs Help.. then all the other parameters are used to specify where on the chart to put the marker.

Go to : http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_params.html#gcharts_dynamic_markers

and scroll down a bit towards the skiing man image..

Comment: yeah i found that page, but i dont see any documentation about how to add a url for a custom image. can you help?

Comment: so you dont want to store the file locally, you need it loaded from a URL in the code? or do you have the option of linking to the custom image and uploading it to the graph server?

Comment: i can store it locally yes, and its on the same server as where the graphs are build. i dont mind really how its implemented, as long as i can use http://pastebin.com/i/nyan.png this image as a marker.

Comment: ok i thought so, erm i may setup my own chart now to test for you but also try putting "d=/i/nyan.png" into your chart like in my example above, an di will try myself on a chart now

Comment: cool, thanks for helping. the d=/i/nyan.png didnt work for me.

Comment: i may have found something im not sure... https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&chld=ski|bb|Wheeee!|000000|00ff00 if you go to that link, ski is the file stored locally on Google servers so maybe if you could put this in your code, and store your file in the same folder, then link to it? just an idea

Comment: This is a blocker for me as well. :( I think we can only use those on the icon_list in http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html#icon_list Any more ideas?